# How to adjust height of individual, static UITableViewCells in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the height of an individual static cell in the heightForRowAtIndexPath table view method.

I am able to change the height of all of the cells if I return a number, but when I call

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) //Get the cell so I can compare its tag

It crashes.

If that cell had the same tag as my static cell, I would give it a custom height. When calling that line thought, it crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the whole code ? And the error message you get ?

Comment: Its EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but I believe it is because you can not use cellForRowAtIndexPath with static cells, I need an alternative

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for every cells of the `UITableView` but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can only be used for displayed cell. So you definitely have to find another way. Do you know exactly where these specific cells are displayed ? I mean, is there a link between the `indexPath` and the tag ?

Comment: What do you mean by link between tag and index path? The link was supposed to be the cellForRowAtIndexPath cell tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your table view is static, you don't need to adjust the heights! Just set the height by dragging the little white square in the storyboard:

[image]

If you want to change your cell's heights dynamically at runtime, then why did you create a static table in the first place? Change the table view to dynamic prototypes and implement the appropriate methods. Static cells are not meant for this purpose.